# How to make OnListItemSelected for a custom listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am doing a project at the moment and i have a listview which is filled with data from HTTP Get request. Now i want to make it when a certain item of the listview is clicked it send HTTP Post request to my server. The problem is that i have no idea how to :

1) Make an OnClick method for every different item
2) Get the ID of my fyrst HTTP Get request and assign it for my HTTP Post.

This is my GET Request :

```
public class TestGet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(params[0]);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String chunk = null;
            while ((chunk = br.readLine()) != null) {

                str.append(chunk + "\n");
            }
            result = str.toString();

            JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(json_data.getString("Sent")=="true"){
                DBQuestion qa = new DBQuestion();
                qa.setName(json_data.getString("ParticipantName"));
                qa.setQuestion(json_data.getString("QuestionText"));
                qa.setId(json_data.getString("Id"));
                qa.setScore(json_data.getString("Votes"));
                questions.add(qa);
                }
                else i+=1;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is my custom adapter :

```
public class qa_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<DBQuestion> {

private Context context;
private int layoutId;
private List<DBQuestion> data;
public qa_adapter(Context context, int resource, List<DBQuestion> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
this.context=context;
layoutId=resource;
data = objects;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
View row = inflater.inflate(layoutId, parent,false);
TextView twName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_qa_row_name);
twName.setText(data.get(position).getName());
TextView twQuestion = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_qa_row_question);
twQuestion.setText(data.get(position).getQuestion());
TextView twVotes = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_qa_row_votes);
twVotes.setText("Votes: "+data.get(position).getScore());

return row;
}
```

and I still havent made my HTTP Post.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you created any Custom Adapter?